# Web scraping: Extract text in R using RVEST

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm doing work for college using R, how I can extract information "**| 20 de Novembro de 2015**" using RVEST package? I tried to get the class "widget-info" but brought a "widget-author" class also

```
<div class="home-list-content">
            <span class="widget-info">
                <span class="widget-author">
                    Rúben Campanacho
                </span> 
                | 20 de Novembro de 2015
            </span>
            <h2>
                LG Pay é o sistema de pagamentos móveis da LG
            </h2>
        </div>
```

My code:

```
pagina <- read_html("http://www.tecnologia.com.pt")
    data <- pagina %>% 
      html_nodes(".widget-info") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      as.data.frame()
```

The result:

```
Rúben Campanacho | 20 de Novembro de 2015
```

I want just **| 20 de Novembro de 2015**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt <- 'Rúben Campanacho | 20 de Novembro de 2015'

gsub('^((\\w+)[[:space:]]){2}', '', txt)
```

Returns:

```
"| 20 de Novembro de 2015"
```